# How to create unit test dependency injection with Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection, frameworks

For example, I want to create a user API
with a dependency injection structure like this

```
func Bootstrap(config *BootstrapConfig) {
// setup repositories
userRepository := repository.NewUserRepository(config.Log)
// setup producer
userProducer := messaging.NewUserProducer(config.Producer, config.Log)
// setup use cases
userUseCase := usecase.NewUserUseCase(config.DB, config.Log, config.Validate, userRepository, userProducer)
// setup controller
userController := http.NewUserController(userUseCase, config.Log)
routeConfig := route.RouteConfig{
    App:               config.App,
    UserController:    userController,
}
routeConfig.Setup()
}
```

Then, I want to create an unit test for the user creation API, but I don't want real interaction with the database or mocking. Since the userUseCase requires a repository, it means we'll create a mock userRepository for the SaveUserToDB function.

Is it the right way to use a method like this?

```
mockRepo.On("SaveUserToDB", mock.Anything, mock.AnythingOfType("*repository.User")).Return(nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency injection requires the dependencies to actually be injected. `Bootstrap` is creating its dependencies, so it can be argued this isn't dependency injection. If you use `Bootstrap` in your test, then this is definitely not dependency injection.

So you need to change `func Bootstrap(config *BootstrapConfig)` to at least `func Bootstrap(config *BootstrapConfig, userRepository *repository.User)`.

Then, in your test, you'd pass `mockRepo` to `Bootstrap`.

```
func Bootstrap(config *BootstrapConfig, userRepository *repository.User) {
    // setup producer
    userProducer := messaging.NewUserProducer(config.Producer, config.Log)
    // setup use cases
    userUseCase := usecase.NewUserUseCase(config.DB, config.Log, config.Validate, userRepository, userProducer)
    // setup controller
    userController := http.NewUserController(userUseCase, config.Log)
    routeConfig := route.RouteConfig{
        App:               config.App,
        UserController:    userController,
    }
    routeConfig.Setup()
}

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    mockRepo := mocks.NewUserRepository(config.Log)
    Bootstrap(config, mockRepo)
    mockRepo.On("SaveUserToDB", mock.Anything).Return(nil)
    …
}
```

`Bootstrap` should not create any dependency, so you should apply this to `userProducer`, `userUseCase`, etc.